# Idiomatic way to write a typescript function with casting

Tags: typescript

Please take a look at this TypeScript code:

```
interface PetrolEngineProperties {
    cylinders: number;
    capacity: number;
}

interface ElectricEngineProperties {
    numberOfBatteries: number;
    batteryCellSize: number;
}

function initializeCarEngine(engineProperties: PetrolEngineProperties | ElectricEngineProperties) {
    if (engineProperties instanceof ElectricEngineProperties) {
        // Do something with Electric Engine properties
    } else if (engineProperties instanceof PetrolEngineProperties) {
        // Do something with Petrol engine properties
        console.log('Petrol engine was started');
    }
}
```

Why does the above approach not work, and what is the correct idiomatic way to handle it.

I am a beginner in the TypeScript world, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the approach in your question is that you're trying to control JavaScript runtime behavior based on TypeScript type information that is only available at compile time.

The JavaScript runtime just sees an `engineProperties` *object*, and is not aware of any of your TypeScript interfaces or types, which is why `instanceof` or `typeof` don't work for this case. There are a couple of approaches you could consider:

### 1. Use classes instead of interfaces or types

JavaScript has support for [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), so TypeScript class information will survive compilation and be available to the JavaScript runtime. This means that you can use the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator:

```
class PetrolEngineProperties {
    constructor(
        public cylinders: number,
        public capacity: number
    ) {}
}

class ElectricEngineProperties {
    constructor(
        public numberOfBatteries: number,
        public batteryCellSize: number
    ) {}
}

type EngineProperties = PetrolEngineProperties | ElectricEngineProperties;

function initializeCarEngine(engineProperties: EngineProperties) {
    if (engineProperties instanceof ElectricEngineProperties) {
        console.log('Electric engine was started');
    } else if (engineProperties instanceof PetrolEngineProperties) {
        console.log('Petrol engine was started');
    }
}

initializeCarEngine(new ElectricEngineProperties(2, 6));
```

### 2. Use a discriminated union

Add a discriminant property to your types and create a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions):

```
interface PetrolEngineProperties {
    kind: 'PETROL';
    cylinders: number;
    capacity: number;
}

interface ElectricEngineProperties {
    kind: 'ELECTRIC';
    numberOfBatteries: number;
    batteryCellSize: number;
}

type EngineProperties = PetrolEngineProperties | ElectricEngineProperties;

function initializeCarEngine(engineProperties: EngineProperties) {
    if (engineProperties.kind === 'ELECTRIC') {
        console.log('Electric engine was started');
    } else if (engineProperties.kind === 'PETROL') {
        console.log('Petrol engine was started');
    }
}

initializeCarEngine({
    kind: 'PETROL',
    cylinders: 8,
    capacity: 2400
});
```

### 3. Write type predicates

If you find yourself in a situation where you can't or don't want to add properties to your objects, you can create [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to convince the TypeScript compiler that objects are of a certain type based on their existing contents:

```
interface PetrolEngineProperties {
    cylinders: number;
    capacity: number;
}

interface ElectricEngineProperties {
    numberOfBatteries: number;
    batteryCellSize: number;
}

type EngineProperties = PetrolEngineProperties | ElectricEngineProperties;

function initializeCarEngine(engineProperties: EngineProperties) {
    if (isElectric(engineProperties)) {
        console.log('Electric engine was started');
    } else if (isPetrol(engineProperties)) {
        console.log('Petrol engine was started');
    }
}

function isElectric(engineProperties: EngineProperties)
        : engineProperties is ElectricEngineProperties {
    return 'numberOfBatteries' in engineProperties
        && 'batteryCellSize' in engineProperties;
}

function isPetrol(engineProperties: EngineProperties)
        : engineProperties is PetrolEngineProperties {
    return 'cylinders' in engineProperties
        && 'capacity' in engineProperties;
}

initializeCarEngine({ cylinders: 8, capacity: 2400 });
```

There are other possible solutions, but the main thing to keep in mind is that in TypeScript, most of the type information disappears at compile time, and you cannot use it as a basis for runtime decisions.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the discriminated union is the most idiomatic option out of these and it's how I've done similar things.

Comment: @ChristianLegge Agreed, at least for the case where the data is under your control and you're free to add a discriminant.

Comment: Excellent well written answer. Thank you so much!